# ffmpeg: 'Protocol not found' for normal file name

Tags: ffmpeg

Every then and now `ffmpeg` tells me

```
myfile.avi: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:myfile.avi
```

if executing `ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p myfile.mp4`.

Using `ffmpeg -i file:myfile.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p myfile.mp4` then fails:

```
file:myfile.avi: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:file:myfile.avi
```

Executing the same (out of bash history) after reboot (normally I just go into `pm-suspend-hybrid`) works, converting from .avi to .mp4 like expected.

Any ideas what might be the reason and how to fix this?

---

complete in-/output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -pix_fmt yuv420p myfile.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.2.9-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --disable-everything --disable-all --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-avutil --enable-fft --enable-rdft --enable-static --enable-libopus --disable-bzlib --disable-error-resilience --disable-iconv --disable-lzo --disable-network --disable-schannel --disable-sdl --disable-symver --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --disable-securetransport --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-nvenc --enable-decoder='vorbis,libopus,flac' --enable-decoder='pcm_u8,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_f32le' --enable-decoder='pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw' --enable-demuxer='ogg,matroska,wav,flac' --enable-parser='opus,vorbis,flac' --extra-cflags=-I/ssd/trunk_blink_tot/src/third_party/opus/src/include --optflags='"-O2"' --enable-decoder='theora,vp8' --enable-parser='vp3,vp8' --enable-pic --enable-decoder='aac,h264,mp3' --enable-demuxer='aac,mp3,mov' --enable-parser='aac,h264,mpegaudio' --enable-lto
  avcodec     configuration: --disable-everything --disable-all --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-avutil --enable-fft --enable-rdft --enable-static --enable-libopus --disable-bzlib --disable-error-resilience --disable-iconv --disable-lzo --disable-network --disable-schannel --disable-sdl --disable-symver --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --disable-securetransport --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-nvenc --enable-decoder='vorbis,libopus,flac' --enable-decoder='pcm_u8,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_f32le' --enable-decoder='pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw' --enable-demuxer='ogg,matroska,wav,flac' --enable-parser='opus,vorbis,flac' --extra-cflags=-I/ssd/trunk_blink_tot/src/third_party/opus/src/include --optflags='"-O2"' --enable-decoder='theora,vp8' --enable-parser='vp3,vp8' --enable-pic --enable-decoder='aac,h264,mp3' --enable-demuxer='aac,mp3,mov' --enable-parser='aac,h264,mpegaudio' --enable-lto
  avformat    configuration: --disable-everything --disable-all --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-avutil --enable-fft --enable-rdft --enable-static --enable-libopus --disable-bzlib --disable-error-resilience --disable-iconv --disable-lzo --disable-network --disable-schannel --disable-sdl --disable-symver --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --disable-securetransport --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-nvenc --enable-decoder='vorbis,libopus,flac' --enable-decoder='pcm_u8,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_f32le' --enable-decoder='pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw' --enable-demuxer='ogg,matroska,wav,flac' --enable-parser='opus,vorbis,flac' --extra-cflags=-I/ssd/trunk_blink_tot/src/third_party/opus/src/include --optflags='"-O2"' --enable-decoder='theora,vp8' --enable-parser='vp3,vp8' --enable-pic --enable-decoder='aac,h264,mp3' --enable-demuxer='aac,mp3,mov' --enable-parser='aac,h264,mpegaudio' --enable-lto
  avdevice    configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  avfilter    configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  avresample  configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  swscale     configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  swresample  configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  postproc    configuration: --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mips32r6 --disable-mips64r6 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-msa --disable-libopencv --disable-podpages --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opengl --enable-openssl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --toolchain=hardened --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libx264 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --disable-opencl --enable-libmfx --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 33.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 55.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  5.100
myfile.avi: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:myfile.avi?
```

Mulvya asked for following:

```
$ ffmpeg -protocols -v 0
Supported file protocols:
Input:
  async
  bluray
  cache
  concat
  crypto
  data
  ffrtmpcrypt
  ffrtmphttp
  file
  ftp
  gopher
  hls
  http
  httpproxy
  https
  mmsh
  mmst
  pipe
  rtmp
  rtmpe
  rtmps
  rtmpt
  rtmpte
  rtmpts
  rtp
  sctp
  srtp
  subfile
  tcp
  tls
  udp
  udplite
  unix
Output:
  crypto
  ffrtmpcrypt
  ffrtmphttp
  file
  ftp
  gopher
  http
  httpproxy
  https
  icecast
  md5
  pipe
  prompeg
  rtmp
  rtmpe
  rtmps
  rtmpt
  rtmpte
  rtmpts
  rtp
  sctp
  srtp
  tee
  tcp
  tls
  udp
  udplite
  unix
```

Comparing the `ldd` output (suggested by andcoz) gives a difference of

```
$ diff ldd-not-working-libs-only ldd-working-libs-only
2d1
<   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so 
16d14
<   librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 
88a87
>   librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
```

Full output:

```
$ cat ldd-not-working
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff303e5000)
    /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so (0x00007f8fb7d89000)
    libavdevice.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavdevice.so.57 (0x00007f8fb7b5b000)
    libavfilter.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so.6 (0x00007f8fb76da000)
    libavformat.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.57 (0x00007f8fb7295000)
    libavcodec.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.57 (0x00007f8fb5b6e000)
    libavresample.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavresample.so.3 (0x00007f8fb594c000)
    libpostproc.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpostproc.so.54 (0x00007f8fb572e000)
    libswresample.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.2 (0x00007f8fb550f000)
    libswscale.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.4 (0x00007f8fb527e000)
    libavutil.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.55 (0x00007f8fb4ff5000)
    libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007f8fb4dd5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8fb4ad1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8fb48b4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8fb4515000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8fb430d000)
    libXv.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 (0x00007f8fb4108000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8fb3dc8000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f8fb3bb6000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8fb398e000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f8fb378a000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f8fb3582000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f8fb337e000)
    libcdio_paranoia.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_paranoia.so.1 (0x00007f8fb3176000)
    libcdio_cdda.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_cdda.so.1 (0x00007f8fb2f6e000)
    libsndio.so.6.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.6.1 (0x00007f8fb2d5e000)
    libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0x00007f8fb2b17000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f8fb280a000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8fb24ee000)
    libdc1394.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22 (0x00007f8fb2277000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8fb2005000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f8fb1db4000)
    libcaca.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 (0x00007f8fb1aeb000)
    libraw1394.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw1394.so.11 (0x00007f8fb18db000)
    libavc1394.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavc1394.so.0 (0x00007f8fb16d6000)
    librom1394.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librom1394.so.0 (0x00007f8fb14d1000)
    libiec61883.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiec61883.so.0 (0x00007f8fb12c4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8fb10c0000)
    libvidstab.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libvidstab.so.1.0 (0x00007f8fb0eab000)
    libtesseract.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.3 (0x00007f8fb0708000)
    librubberband.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librubberband.so.2 (0x00007f8fb04d2000)
    libmfx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmfx.so.0 (0x00007f8fb02be000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f8fb00a7000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f8fafdf8000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f8fafbba000)
    libbs2b.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbs2b.so.0 (0x00007f8faf9b4000)
    libass.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.9 (0x00007f8faf783000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f8faf474000)
    libopenmpt.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 (0x00007f8faf0e5000)
    libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007f8faee98000)
    libbluray.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.2 (0x00007f8faec4b000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f8fae8b2000)
    libchromaprint.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libchromaprint.so.1 (0x00007f8fae69a000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f8fae48a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8fae270000)
    libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007f8fadfe3000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f8fadccf000)
    libx265.so.116 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.116 (0x00007f8fad649000)
    libx264.so.150 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.150 (0x00007f8fad2ce000)
    libvpx.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.4 (0x00007f8face91000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f8facbe8000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f8fac9bc000)
    libvo-amrwbenc.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvo-amrwbenc.so.0 (0x00007f8fac7a2000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f8fac563000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f8fac345000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f8fac12c000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007f8fabf24000)
    libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007f8fabd17000)
    libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f8fabac8000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007f8fab88d000)
    libopenh264.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenh264.so.2 (0x00007f8fab598000)
    libopencore-amrwb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencore-amrwb.so.0 (0x00007f8fab384000)
    libopencore-amrnb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencore-amrnb.so.0 (0x00007f8fab15a000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f8faaec3000)
    libkvazaar.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkvazaar.so.3 (0x00007f8faac3d000)
    libilbc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libilbc.so.2 (0x00007f8faaa26000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f8faa819000)
    libfdk-aac.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfdk-aac.so.1 (0x00007f8faa561000)
    libcrystalhd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrystalhd.so.3 (0x00007f8faa346000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f8faa120000)
    libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007f8fa9ebd000)
    libvdpau.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau.so.1 (0x00007f8fa9cb9000)
    libva-x11.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.1 (0x00007f8fa9ab3000)
    libva-drm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm.so.1 (0x00007f8fa98b0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8fb861a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8fa96ac000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8fa94a6000)
    libcdio.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.13 (0x00007f8fa9281000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f8fa906b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8fa8ce9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8fa8ad2000)
    libpulse-simple.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0 (0x00007f8fa88cd000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f8fa86c2000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f8fa84bf000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f8fa82af000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f8fa80a4000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f8fa7ea1000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f8fa7c9b000)
    libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f8fa7a99000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f8fa788a000)
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f8fa7682000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f8fa7442000)
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8fa7229000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8fa6fff000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f8fa6dfc000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f8fa6bf9000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f8fa69f2000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f8fa67f0000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f8fa65c1000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f8fa63be000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f8fa61b8000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f8fa5fb6000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f8fa5d9b000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f8fa5b96000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f8fa5986000)
    libpulsecommon-10.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-10.0.so (0x00007f8fa5703000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f8fa54b3000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f8fa52ad000)
    libslang.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 (0x00007f8fa4dc5000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00007f8fa4b95000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f8fa496b000)
    liblept.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5 (0x00007f8fa44fb000)
    libsamplerate.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamplerate.so.0 (0x00007f8fa418f000)
    libfftw3.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3 (0x00007f8fa3d92000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f8fa3b5f000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f8fa38ca000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f8fa36b6000)
    libmpg123.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpg123.so.0 (0x00007f8fa3457000)
    libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0x00007f8fa324e000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f8fa2ee7000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f8fa2c82000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f8fa2a4e000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f8fa283b000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f8fa2604000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f8fa23cf000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f8fa214c000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f8fa1f41000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f8fa1d38000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f8fa1a24000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f8fa17f7000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f8fa15ed000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f8fa13e4000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f8fb87a0000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f8fa11c7000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f8fa0fbf000)
    libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6 (0x00007f8fa0db9000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f8fb8714000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f8fa0baf000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f8fa0937000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f8fa0731000)
    libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f8fa04c6000)
    libgif.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so.7 (0x00007f8fa02bc000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f8fa0045000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f8f9fde4000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8f9fad0000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f8f9f8a3000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f8f9f5fc000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f8f9f3ee000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f8f9f1e9000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f8f9efc1000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f8f9edaf000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f8f9eb97000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f8f9e920000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8f9e709000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f8f9e4fb000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f8f9e288000)
```

Comment: What does `ffmpeg -protocols -v 0` list?

Comment: Do you have the message about `library configuration mismatch` also in case the conversion succeeds?

Comment: yes, it always appears

Comment: can you do `ls -l myfile.avi`? i am suspicious that the file name begins with a space symbol...

Comment: As to complete John Smith comment, is it with any avi files ? or only from a certain source, and how frequent is that ? Also what is the real filename ? It seems that filename handling might be tricky sometime witth ffmpeg: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2303

Comment: Can you do compare the output of `ldd $( which ffmpeg )` executed when ffmpeg works with the one executed when ffmpeg does not work?

Comment: I can't really tell how frequent it is, may be in 1/2 cases (trying once a week, with several hibernations in the days between), but once it stopped working, it won't work again until reboot. I've saved ldd output of the now working conversion, waiting for a failed try...

Comment: The file name is exactly 'myfile.avi' and I tried with files from different sources,

Comment: when this problem occurs, is `myfile.avi` accessible by other means?  (can it be played with vlc, mplayer, etc, or read with other tools?)  this sounds more like a problem with the underlying filesystem coming out of hibernation than an ffmpeg issue.

Comment: the file is fully normal usable by any other means

Comment: @andcoz: like you can see with the output added above, the difference is the `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so`. Having it loaded is the cause, like I could validate. It's loaded by Vivaldi browser.

Comment: Please specify the exact file name, note answer below on the fact that ":" cannot be used in the filename.

Comment: @Roel: As you can see in my own answer from last year, below, the colon has nothing to do with my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @andcoz lead me onto the right way: the problem exists as long as `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so` is loaded.

In my case this happens in some special use case:

The `libffmpeg.so` is used by the Vivaldi browser for showing proprietary video formats (H.264). 
If I download a file via Vivaldi, and then go to its download panel, right click on the downloaded file and select 'Show in file manager', my file manager opens. It runs in the 'context' of the browser, so when I go a step further, and open a terminal out of that file manager session, this also runs in the context of Vivaldi. 
For me this means, that there are a few environment variables set, which are not there, if I start a normal terminal session (not out of Vivaldi context).
These environment variables contain (among others) a `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so`. As that one causes `libffmpeg.so` to be loaded when running my conversion with `ffmpeg`, I tried an `unset LD_PRELOAD` in the terminal session and after that my conversion ran again fully normal.

So this is where the 'then and now' problem came from, I just was not aware of the case I am in a different environment variable context when starting my program chain out of Vivaldi.

Thx everyone for helping out.

Answer (score 25):

I came to this topic for the message, just to add one tip for users, I found out that if the filename itself has ':' in it would cause the problem, as some programs generate files with the time stamp like "audio 12:34:14.ogg"

Comment: Excellent answer. Using ":" in the filename confuses ffmpeg (and it does not matter whether you use `"`" or `'` to surround the file name, and backslash escaping does not work for ":"). The only possible solution is to [temporarily] remove ":" from the filename.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not true. The proper solution is to add `file:` before the output (not input) filename, then ":" in it will not cause issues.

Comment: Or just prepend `./` before the file name. FFMpeg appears to check for patterns such as `http:` or `https:` at the start of the input parameter and attempts to resolve this as a URL and download that file.

Comment: Wow, not only this fixed ffprobe. But also made my samsung tv recognize the file in the usb.

Answer (score 13):

For me "Protocol not found" error was caused by ":" in the output filename. Removing it and then adding back again sounds like a workaround and unnecessary complication. Fortunately I was able to find the solution - just add `file:` in front of the filename. For example this will work even if `$file` contains substring like "09:02:21":

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec copy "file:${file:r:t}".mov
```

In the command above only `file:` part is important in context of this answer; but in case if somebody wonders what `${file:r:t}` does, it in zsh shell removes absolute path and extension sub-strings from the `$file` variable. Note that `file:` was not needed for the input filename in this case but was necessary for the output filename even though both contain multiple ":" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this unpredictable behavior of `ffmpeg` (does not work first, but works after reboot), I would think that the program installation is somehow *broken*. The message

```
WARNING: library configuration mismatch
```

which you supply says that there is some problem in the installation. Googling this warning gives a feeling that the problem has existed for years, even with clean installations, but was never fully resolved. The most reasonable explanation, which I found, is following

> Well, the warning is printed whenever you use a copy of the 'ffmpeg' binary with a copy of libavcodec (or any other library provided by the ffmpeg source package) that has been built with a different configuration. Which is the whole point of the 'libavcodec-extra*' packages: Enable additional functionality. [(source)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg-extra/+bug/730159)

If you follow this link you'll find some recipes how to resolve this issue. The most frequent one is [(1)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg-extra/+bug/730159), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.link/question/713624/how-do-i-get-rid-of-ffmpeg-warning-library-configuration-mismatch-message)

```
sudo apt remove libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
```

but it does not work for everybody. So may be the best solution would be to reinstall ffmpeg and/or the needed libraries.

p.s. Do not judge me too strict if I am wrong in my understanding of your situation and please let us know if any of this helps.

Comment: I do not have this package on my Debian and none of the `libavcodec-extra*` packages is currently installed.